# Are you able to cast abilities while rooted by rengar?

Tags: league-of-legends

I just played against a rengar who got fed my team and well he used his ultimate rooted me under my own turret and for some reason i could not use my ultimate as tristana and i had vision of him  before he could even leap as he did turret dive so my ult should have hit him yet I was unable to use it he then one shot me with sword of divine and q and poof. according to this [article](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Crowd_control) while rooted you should still be able to cast abilities yet i could do absolutely nothing but just watch him leap and kill me even though I had tried to cast my ult it did not go off he did this multiple times(turret dives ( he was insanely fed)) and each time my ult would not go off if he rooted me before the leap however when he leap q'd my ult worked and i would survive with almost no hp.... is that how a rengar empowered e works cause last I checked its just a root

Comment: There isn't enough information to properly answer why it didnt work for you. Bola strike is either a slow or a snare/root, never a stun, so the only possibility really is that he killed you before it went off, and that's unlikely as the ult has a pretty fast cast time. It isn't a known bug, so you either were canceling your ult cast, lagging, there's something in the story we're missing, or something we can't know.

Comment: A root causes you to lose control of any movement of your character ([source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Suppression#Suppression)). Tristana faces her target when ulting (you can't ult behind you without rotating to face whomever you are ulting. I can imagine that the game won't let you ult when rooted if your target is not in front of you (because ulting behind you would have to cause movement). I didn't test anything, it's just speculation, that's why I didn't post this as an answer.

Comment: (Almost) all abilities in the game require you to be facing in the direction it is being shot. The game has no turn speed, at least as a mechanic. If this was the case, you would only ever be able to cast spells if you happened to fire them in the exact direction you happened to be facing when rooted.

Comment: Characters do have angled casting animations though. Most champions won't turn around if you cast something generally in front of them, while they do turn if you cast generally behind them.

Comment: ok well the 4 times he had used his leap i had been expecting it and facing forward to buster shot him away of the 4 times he had jumped me twice my buster shot worked and that was when he used empowered q however when he used his empowered e I could not cast my ultimate and well just blew up which i really do not understand because i was fast enough to hover my mouse over rengar and press R but it just did not go off and i quick cast

Comment: One thing that could have happened is that your cursor wasn't on Rengar when quick casting, making the game try to cast your ult on yourself, which obviously doesn't work. Maybe the targeting box of Rengar got some bug or is too small.

Comment: I personally think it's just much more likely the OP made a mistake as we are all privy to do from time to time. This really feels like a rant to me.

Comment: Do i like need to post a video-_- this happened 4 times I made no mistake tristana is my main adc and again I was like level 17 2 of the 4 times he jumped me but cool thanks for the help...

Answer (score 1):

Rengar has a root that works just as every other root.

You will still be able to cast abilities that **don't require or force movement**.

This means normal casts and skillshots are castable while Gapclosers and flashes aren't.

A good example for this is Lee Sin. You can use your Sonic Wave (1st Q) while rooted (by rengar) but you cannot use your Resonating Strike (2nd Q).

If you weren't able to cast a non-movement ability while rooted it was most likely a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You should have been able to ult him.

Are you sure you were in range ?

It's most likely a bug.

Comment: I was level 17 and level 12 when he jumped me so yes i was in range

Comment: Then it's a bug and should be signaled.